# What are the possible concentration pathways for a 3-species system?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, theoretical-chemistry

Inspired by [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15511/can-a-multi-species-system-oscillate-around-equilibrium), which asks if a multi-species system could oscillate around its equilibrium, I thought about the possible concentration pathways the following more narrow specified system could take:

$$ \ce{A ->[\text{$k_1$}] B} $$
$$ \ce{B ->[\text{$k_2$}] C} $$
$$ \ce{C ->[\text{$k_3$}] A} $$

What I was interested in are the ratio of those concentrations $A:B:C$. The initial conditions are $A(0)=1$, $B(0)=0$, $C(0)=0$. (For simplicity, $[\ce{A}] \equiv A$, and analogous for $B$ and $C$)

> What are the possible concentration pathways for different values of $k_1$, $k_2$ and $k_3$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have a **cyclic** cascade of unimolecular chemical reactions

$$\ce{A} \xrightarrow{\kappa_1} \ce{B} \xrightarrow{\kappa_2} \ce{C} \xrightarrow{\kappa_3} \ce{A}$$

where $\kappa_1, \kappa_2, \kappa_3 > 0$ are the rate constants. Assuming that each chemical reaction in this cascade has [mass action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_mass_action) kinetics, then we have the following system of linear ODEs

$$\begin{bmatrix} \dot a\\ \dot b\\ \dot c\end{bmatrix} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} - \kappa_1 & 0 & \kappa_3\\ \kappa_1 & - \kappa_2 & 0\\ 0 & \kappa_2 & - \kappa_3\end{bmatrix}}_{=: \mathrm M} \begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\\ c\end{bmatrix}$$

where $a := [\ce{A}]$, $b := [\ce{B}]$ and $c := [\ce{C}]$ are the concentrations of the species. Since $\dot a + \dot b + \dot c = 0$, integrating we obtain the following conservation law

$$a (t) + b (t) + c (t) = a_0 + b_0 + c_0$$

where $a_0, b_0, c_0 \geq 0$ are the initial concentrations.

---

#### Stability

The characteristic polynomial of matrix $\mathrm M$ is

$$\det (s \mathrm I_3 - \mathrm M) = s \underbrace{\left( s^2 + (\kappa_1 + \kappa_2 + \kappa_3) s + (\kappa_1 \kappa_2 + \kappa_1 \kappa_3 + \kappa_2 \kappa_3) \right)}_{=: q (s)} = s \, q(s)$$

Since $\kappa_1, \kappa_2, \kappa_3 > 0$, all three coefficients of the (monic) quadratic polynomial $q$ are positive. Hence, both roots of $q$ have negative real parts and, thus, the cyclic cascade is (internally) marginally **stable**. Given nonzero initial concentrations, the concentrations will not grow unbounded. However, due to the zero eigenvalue, the concentrations will not converge to zero either.

---

#### Steady state

If the concentrations of the species do not converge to zero, then to what values do they converge? At steady state, $\dot a = \dot b = \dot c = 0$. Hence, we have the following homogeneous linear system

$$\begin{bmatrix} - \kappa_1 & 0 & \kappa_3\\ \kappa_1 & - \kappa_2 & 0\\ 0 & \kappa_2 & - \kappa_3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \bar a\\ \bar b\\ \bar c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\bar a, \bar b, \bar c$ are the steady state concentrations. Using Gaussian elimination, we eventually obtain a **line** passing through the origin that is parameterized as follows

$$\begin{bmatrix} \bar a\\ \bar b\\ \bar c\end{bmatrix} \in \left\{ \gamma \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\kappa_1}\\ \frac{1}{\kappa_2}\\ \frac{1}{\kappa_3}\end{bmatrix} : \gamma \in \mathbb R \right\}$$

where

$$\tau_1 := \frac{1}{\kappa_1} \qquad\qquad\qquad \tau_2 := \frac{1}{\kappa_2} \qquad\qquad\qquad \tau_3 := \frac{1}{\kappa_3}$$

are **time constants**. Intersecting this line with the **plane**  $\bar a + \bar b + \bar c = a_0 + b_0 + c_0$, we obtain

$$\gamma = \left( \dfrac{1}{\tau_{1} + \tau_{2} + \tau_{3}}\right) \left( a_0 + b_0 +c_0 \right)$$

and, thus, the **steady state** concentrations are

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{rl} & \\ \qquad\bar a &= \left( \dfrac{\tau_{1}}{\tau_{1} + \tau_{2} + \tau_{3}}\right) \left( a_0 + b_0 +c_0 \right)  \qquad \\\\ \qquad\bar b &= \left( \dfrac{\tau_{2}}{\tau_{1} + \tau_{2} + \tau_{3}}\right) \left( a_0 + b_0 +c_0 \right) \qquad\\\\ \qquad\bar c &= \left( \dfrac{\tau_{3}}{\tau_{1} + \tau_{2} + \tau_{3}}\right) \left( a_0 + b_0 +c_0 \right)\\ & \end{array}}$$

If, say, $\kappa_1 \gg \kappa_2, \kappa_3$, i.e., if $\tau_1 \ll \tau_2, \tau_3$, then $\bar a \ll \bar b, \bar c$. If $\kappa_1 = \kappa_2 = \kappa_3$, then $\bar a = \bar b = \bar c$.

Assuming that at least one of $a_0, b_0, c_0$ is nonzero, the **ratios** of the steady state concentrations are

$$\frac{\bar a}{\bar b} = \frac{\kappa_2}{\kappa_1} = \frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2} \qquad\qquad\qquad \frac{\bar a}{\bar c} = \frac{\kappa_3}{\kappa_1} = \frac{\tau_1}{\tau_3} \qquad\qquad\qquad \frac{\bar b}{\bar c} = \frac{\kappa_3}{\kappa_2} = \frac{\tau_2}{\tau_3}$$

Hence, the ratio of the steady state concentrations of two species is the ratio of their time constants.

---

#### Oscillations

Let

$$\Delta (\kappa_1, \kappa_2, \kappa_3) := (\kappa_1 + \kappa_2 + \kappa_3)^2 - 4 (\kappa_1 \kappa_2 + \kappa_1 \kappa_3 + \kappa_2 \kappa_3) \\ = (\kappa_1 - \kappa_2)^2 + (\kappa_1 - \kappa_3)^2 + (\kappa_2 - \kappa_3)^2 - (\kappa_1^2 + \kappa_2^2 + \kappa_3^2)$$

be the discriminant of quadratic polynomial $q$. When $\Delta < 0$, the roots of $q$ have nonzero imaginary parts and, thus, the cyclic cascade will exhibit **damped oscillations**. Hence, when

$$\kappa_1^2 + \kappa_2^2 + \kappa_3^2 > (\kappa_1 - \kappa_2)^2 + (\kappa_1 - \kappa_3)^2 + (\kappa_2 - \kappa_3)^2$$

the cyclic cascade will exhibit oscillatory behavior. Provided that the inequality above is satisfied, the concentrations will oscillate as follows

$$\begin{array}{rl} a (t) &= \bar a + \eta_A \, e^{- \kappa_0 t} \cos( \omega_0 t - \phi_A)\\ b (t) &= \bar b + \eta_B \, e^{- \kappa_0 t} \cos( \omega_0 t - \phi_B)\\ c (t) &= \bar c + \eta_C \, e^{- \kappa_0 t} \cos( \omega_0 t - \phi_C)\end{array}$$

where

$$\begin{array}{rl} \kappa_0 &:= \frac{1}{2} \left( \kappa_1 + \kappa_2 + \kappa_3 \right)\\ \omega_0 &:= \frac 12 \sqrt{\kappa_1^2 + \kappa_2^2 + \kappa_3^2 - (\kappa_1 - \kappa_2)^2 - (\kappa_1 - \kappa_3)^2 - (\kappa_2 - \kappa_3)^2}\end{array}$$

Each species will have its own magnitude and phase lag that are dependent on the initial conditions.

Answer (score 12):

Of course, we can't display every pathway there is. We have to select a wide variety of rate constants to get a "good map" of the parameter-space. The approach I took was this:

1. Construct the differential equations

$$\frac{\mathrm dA}{\mathrm dt} = -k_1 A + k_3 C$$
$$\frac{\mathrm dB}{\mathrm dt} = -k_2 B + k_1 A$$
$$\frac{\mathrm dC}{\mathrm dt} = -k_3 C + k_2 B$$

2. Solve them numerically for every possible combination of 0.1, 1 and 10 for each rate constant and the above stated initial conditions
3. This leads to 27 pathways, which are plotted in a ternary diagram

The title of the ternary diagram is $k_1:k_2:k_3$, which is 0.1 : 0.1 : 0.1 in the first one.

[image]
[image: The solution.]
*(click for larger image)*

Comment: What software did you use to generate these diagrams?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Honestly Im not completely sure, either Python / Matplotlib or R. Maybe I'll find the source code when I'm home.