# Steady state approximation for three-step cycle

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, rate-equation

> How to write the steady state for $\ce{A}?$
> $$\ce{A ->[$k_1$] B ->[$k_2$] C ->[$k_3$] A}$$

Species $\ce{A}$ seems to appear on both side of equation as it uses itself to produce some of itself. I have checked some online tutorials but I found none cover this scenario.

Comment: One approximation could be $\ce{B <=> C}$ and at steady state, $\ce{[B]}$ and $\ce{[C]}$ do not change.

Comment: A, B and C remain constant in this scheme.

Comment: They come to equilibrium with amounts proportional to the ratio of rate constants.  If all k's are equal then the population is 1/3 each.

Comment: [Related](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/22373/30836).